# Random variable and probability calculations

Tags: probability, random-variables

X is a random variable that follows a binomial property, with E(X) = 36 and $\sigma$(X) = 3.

Calculate p(X = $10$)

I know that the variance is V(X) = 9 and I know that I have to use the formulas of E(X) and V(X), but how can I solve it without having the other values of X and each of $p(X_i)$?

Comment: Did you write down the formulas for mean and variance and try to solve them for $n$ and $p$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is a random variable that follow a *binomial distribution*, then it is the count of successes among an amount ($n$) of independent Bernoulli trials with identical success rate ($p$).   We usually summarise this as $X\sim \mathcal {Bin}(n,p)$.

The parameters for this distribution specify its probability mass function $$\mathsf P(X=k)~=~\binom nk p^k(1-p)^k~\mathbf 1_{k\in[0;n]\cap\Bbb N}$$

Further, these parameters ($n,p$) determine the expectation and variance for such a random variable.$$\mathsf E(X)=np\\\mathsf{Var}(X)=np(1-p)$$

So, given the values of the expectation and variance, determine the parameters and hence evaluate the probability $\mathsf P(X=10)$.

Answer (score 0):

The mean of $B(n,p)$ is $np$ and the variance is $np(1-p)$. [See https://stattrek.com/probability-distributions/binomial.aspx ]. It is given that $np=36$ and $np(1-p)=9$. This gives $p=\frac 3 4$ and $n=48$. So the answer is $P(X=10)=\binom {48} {10} (\frac 3 4)^{10} (\frac 1 4)^{38}$.

Comment: Why the downvote?